# PySpark removing Invalid Date time format in column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My date time field format is: 2016-10-15 00:00:00
after using infer schema while saving my data to a parquet file, I have a few rows that don't comply to this format.

How can I collectively remove them in PySpark?

It is causing me problems in my UDF's.

Comment: Please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're parsing the date column and rows with invalid dates are null, which is usually the case:

```
df.filter(col('date').isNotNull())
```

Alternatively, if your date is read as a string, you can parse it using `unix_timestamp`:

```
(
    df
    .select(unix_timestamp('date', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp").alias('date'))
    .filter(col('date').isNotNull())
)
```